# VBA Excel if column doesn't have a specific value

Tags: vba, if-statement

I am trying to prevent a subroutine from running if the column "L" it's working with doesn't have any value "Yes"

```
    If Range("L2:L").WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, "Yes") > 0 Then
    Call DeleteSubparts
    End If
```

There's a problem with my if function and I'm not sure what am I writing wrong. Could someone, please, help me?

Comment: What is `col`?  Where do you define it?  Have you looked at the official documentation for [the `WorksheetFunction` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction) or [the `CountIf` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L2:L100"), "Yes") > 0 Then
    DeleteSubparts
End If
```

The range goes inside the function, thought you should reference both the workbook and worksheet like this:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks("WorkbookName").Worksheets("WorksheetName").Range("L2:L100"), "Yes") > 0 Then
    DeleteSubparts
End If
```

Comment: The syntax seems right, but it doesn't count what I need. It still executes the subroutine I am calling when what I'm trying to do is to not call deletesubparts if column "L" has no value "Yes"

Comment: @Eduards the syntax should count the "Yes" in that column, maybe is the reference. If you don't reference both workbook & worksheet it will count on the active sheet which could be totally a different sheet that the one you intend.

Comment: Hm. Either you write `Range("L:L")` or something like  `Range("L2:L" & lastRow)`